# How to add user id information in the schema and also hide form autoforms?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am learning the ropes of Meteor and kind of lost here. I am using collections2, autoform for building my application. I want to store the collection along with user id information. So that when we retrieve the collection from the server, I want to show only the ones the user created not everything else. here is the schema.

```
    ExercisesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "name": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Name'
    },
    "workout.$.weight": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Weight'
    },
    "workout.$.reps": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Reps'
    },
    "notes": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Notes',
        optional: true
    }
});
```

on the server side I want to show only the workouts created by the user

```
Meteor.publish('exercises', function () {
    return Exercises.find({owner: this.userId});
});
```

When I added the user id to the schema, it shows up in the autoform, I am not sure how to hide it, if I hide it, then possibly I can use hooks in the autoform to add the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the schema you can define the ownerId as type: "hidden"

**schema.js**

```
ExercisesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "name": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Name'
    },
    "ownerId": {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden",
        }
    },
    "workout": {
        //not sure if you need this, you didn't have it in your
        type: [Object], 
        defaultValue: [] 
    },
    "workout.$.weight": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Weight'
    },
    "workout.$.reps": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Reps'
    },
    "notes": {
        type: String,
        label: 'Notes',
        optional: true
    }
});
```

And populate it with the hooks as you said.

**autoFormHooks.js**

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  exerciseForm: {
    formToDoc: function(doc) {
      doc.ownerId = Meteor.userId();
      return doc
    },
  }
});
```

An alternative to using hooks would be to use a quickFields inside of your autoForm for each field that you want to set in the doc, including ownerId.  With this solution you would set the `value` of ownerId to `currentUser`.

```
{{#autoForm collection="Exercises" id="exerciseForm" type="insert"}}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add an Exercise</legend>
    {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
    {{> afQuickField name='notes'}}
    {{> afQuickField name='ownerId' value=currentUserId}}
    {{> afQuickField name='workout'}}
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

**template.js**

```
Template.formTemplate.helpers({
    currentUserId: function () {
        return Meteor.userId();
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have any idea, what could have caused to get following error, "Error: Invalid definition for ownerId field". If I remove autoForm definition, error goes away. Adding the auto form to the schema, error comes back. I have installed simple-schema, collection2 and autoform.

Comment: @challett Following above approach, I get two objects saved at once into collection. Removing the `autoFormHooks.js` solves it

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `before` hook approach:

```
ExercisesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
...
    "ownerId": {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden",
        }
    },
...
});
```

In your template:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Exercises" id="exerciseForm" type="insert"}}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add an Exercise</legend>
    {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
    {{> afQuickField name='notes'}}
    <!-- Notice I've removed the ownerId from here. Will be added before saving to collection -->
    {{> afQuickField name='workout'}}
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Then your `autoform.js`

```
var addUserHook = {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc) {
      if(Meteor.userId()){
        doc.ownerId = Meteor.userId();
      }

      return doc;
    }
  }
}

AutoForm.addHooks('exerciseForm', addUserHook);
```

The above adds the ownerId on the fly just when about to save to collection.

As stated in the docs on [atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform):

> For example, you might want to add the current user's ID to a
>   document before it is inserted. You can use "before", "formToDoc", or
>   "formToModifier" hooks to do this.